# How to check if the set with commas is infinite or finite?

Tags: python, math, numbers, set, infinite

I am trying to use the method math.isinf to find out if the set is infinite.
The set is

```
{...,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,...}
```

```
import math
Infinte_set = {-math.inf,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,math.inf}
print(math.isinf(Infinte_set))
```

I was expecting True or False but what I got is this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-3d08b071af6f> in <module>
      5 import math
      6 Infinte_set = {-math.inf,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,math.inf}
----> 7 print(math.isinf(Infinte_set))

TypeError: must be real number, not set
```

Comment: When a function doesn't do what you expected, it's a good idea to read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isinf): "`math.isinf(x)`
Return `True` if x is a positive or negative infinity, and `False` otherwise."

Comment: `print(not Infinte_set.isdisjoint({math.inf, -math.inf}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `min` value or `max` value of the set in `math.isinf` function to check for infinity.

```py
print(math.isinf(min(Infinte_set)) or math.isinf(max(Infinte_set)))
```

`math.isinf(min(Infinte_set))` -> `min(Infinte_set)` would be the minimum numerical value, in your case it would be -infinity.

`math.isinf(max(Infinte_set))` -> `max(Infinte_set)` would be the minimum numerical value, in your case it would be +infinity.

If in case you don't know how `or` works:

```
True or False -> True
False or True -> True
False or False -> False
True or True -> True
```